# Google maps API can't get the longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps

i'm trying to get the longitude and latitude for an address with the google maps api, but I don't know how to do it?This is an example of what i'm trying:

```
GoogleObjectAdress("New york") -> and it should return the longitude and latitude for me!
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2.x&amp;key=YourApiKey"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
geocoder.getLatLng("New York", function(point) { 
    //code
});
```

For more information, read the [documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/).